# Output of the below program: Signed Byte Operation

Tags: java, byte, signed

Can someone please let me know Output of the below program and how signed byte works

```
public class OppositeSigns 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      byte a =-2;
      byte b= -1;
      opp(a,b);
    }

    static void opp(byte x,byte y)
    {
      byte z;
      z= (byte)(x^y);
      System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1):

```
-1 is 11111111 in binary
-2 is 11111110 in binary
```

when you XOR the two numbers, you get

```
      00000001
```

which is 1

Comment: Except you're not XORing those two bytes. You're XORing the 32-bit integers. The answer ends up being the same, but it's worth knowing that integer promotion happens first.

Comment: Thanks a lot@eran. But how signed byte is represented  is -1= 10000001?

Comment: @RahulLamba Read about [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)